# String in byte form to original string in java

Tags: java, string, arrays

I wrote a code writing 8 different values of sine in byte form (using .getbytes) into a text file.

After I run it a file is created containing the following:
    [B@5f18cd5
    [B@1c515979
    [B@20c92575
    [B@75ba3523
    [B@f4c7f77
    [B@67446579
    [B@3b621fe6
    [B@271c537f

So far so good...

I'd now like to inverse this whole process in another Java project. For this I need to know how to turn for example [B@1c515979 back to it's initial value which is 0.7071.

I tried to use

```
System.out.println("Text [Byte Format] : " + bytes.toString());
```

with which I hoped to convert the byte code back to string.
The problem though, is that  since I'm reading from a text file I guess the read data is string anyway, so actually I'm just turning strings into strings.

This is my status quo... Anyone got an idea?

Thanks for listening.

Comment: why don\t you store the values as a text in the first place?

Comment: Do you call the `getBytes()` on a String? Then you should use `new String(bytes);` instead of `bytes.toString();`.

Comment: "So far so good" ... No, not good. You're writing the data in the wrong way. The [B@... strings you see are not representations of byte arrays. You get these because arrays don't have a `toString` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[B@5f18cd5` is not a byte, it's a string representation of a reference.
You can't turn them back into anything.

```
public class Ref {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Ref());
    }
}
//Outputs: Ref@19e0bfd
```

`foo@address` is a reference. You're not actually writing values into the file but references as String. `B[` means that you're writing `byte[]` into a file but not the actual bytes *in* that array.

**Update**

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException,
        IOException {
    final File f = new File("/tmp/output");

    final ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream(f));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        final double d = Math.sin(i);
        System.out.println(d);
        oos.writeDouble(d);
    }

    oos.flush();
    oos.close();

    System.out.println("---");

    final ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(f));

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        System.out.println(ois.readDouble());

    ois.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You've already lost all the important data. Calling `toString()` on a `byte[]` doesn't give you anything useful, because arrays in Java don't override `toString()`... so you're getting the implementation from `Object`, which just indicates the type and the hash code (which is effectively the identity hash code, for arrays). If you modify the content of the byte array and call `toString()` on it, you'll get the same value.

Instead, you need to change how you're saving the data. If you can avoid needing a text file at all, that would be ideal... but if you *do* need a text file, the simplest option is probably to convert the binary data to base64, e.g. using [`java.util.Base64`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html):

```
String text = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
// Write out text...

...

// String text = // read from a file
byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

The strings that you show (`[B@5f18cd5`  etc)  are not encodings of the byte values. Rather they are the output of the default `toString()` method of `java.lang.Object`: 'class name' + "@" 'hash code in hex'.

You can't convert that back into the contents of the bytes.

You need to change the way in which you write the bytes. Try `DataOutputStream` to write each byte array.

For each array, write the length of the array using `DataOutputStream.writeInt()` and then the bytes themselves. To read them back, use `DataInputStream`, first read the length, then construct a byte array of that length, and then read the data back into the array.